# Moongoose Model.find() returns empty array when i have uppercase letter in the table name

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When the table name includes a capital letter (e.g. fooBar), Moongoose Model.find() returns an empty array.  If I change both the table name and the search string to be lowercase without changing anything else - it works fine.

Is this expected?

Comment: I think when you set your model you should give it the third parameter in mongoose.model('name', schema, 'fooBar') the fooBar is the camel case name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have read somewhere about collection names being treated by default as lowercase inside of mongoose.  I always circumvent it by using models:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const FoobarSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String }
}, { collection: 'fooBar' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('fooBar', FoobarSchema);
```

The important part is what you name the **collection** in the Schema definition.  In the export that 'fooBar' can be named whatever you want and is a means to reference the model in your code.